# Lampp Centos 7 change php version to 7.3

Tags: php, centos7, lampp

I have a Centos 7 server with Lampp and PHP 7.2.26. I want to upgrade it to PHP 7.3. I have updated php to 7.3 and now, `php -v` reports 7.3.23, but `phpinfo()` reports 7.2.26. How can I configure lampp to use php 7.3?
Updated: I don't want to have multiple versions of PHP. I only want to have PHP 7.3. I want to stop using 7.2.26 and use 7.3 only. I have read some post about using multiple version of PHP but no one solves my question.
I think I have to change some configuration files in lampp installation to use the new php version, but I don't know what files should I change.

Comment: notice the "A" in lampp.  You may need to update your apache config (LoadModule) to load the new libphp7.so module from the 7.3 distribution.

Comment: Not a programming question. Your configuation file research process should involve looking at things, figuring out which SAPI is used, and how the newer version was installed. (None of which is explained in this question. Hence unanswerable.)